# Prevent Googlebot from running a function

Tags: jquery, googlebot

We have implemented a new Number of Visits function on our site that saves a row in our Views database when a company profile on our site is accessed. This is done using a server-side "/addVisit" function that is run each time a page (company profile) is loaded. Unfortunately, this means we had 400+ Visits from Googlebot last night.

Since we do want Google to index these pages, we can't exclude Googlebot on these pages using robots.txt.

I have also read that running this function using a jQuery $.get() will not stop Googlebot.

Is the only working solution is to exclude known bot IPs or are there options?

Or possibly using a jQuery $.get(/addVisit) with a robots.txt exclude /addVisit will stop googlebot and other bots from running this function?

Comment: Both answers bellow appear to do the trick. I decided to use a jQuery $.post(/addVisit) + robots.txt disallow /addVisit. I'm sure there are advantages to both using jQuery or using client side. For me, it felt more correct to use robots.txt to tell robots not to follow the link than to parse out the robot User Agents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `robots.txt` file in the root directory of your website, and add:

```
User-agent: Google
Disallow: /addVisit
```

You can also use `*` instead of `Google`, so that `/addvisit` doesn't get indexed at by any engine. Search engines start always looking for `/robots.txt`. If this file exists, they parse the contents and respect the applied restrictions.

For more information, see http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html.

Comment: Right, but this will only work if I use jQuery $.get(/addVisit) correct?

Comment: This will only break index bots. The traffic between normal clients and the server is not affected in any way (read the explanation of `robots.txt` in my answer).

Comment: Correct. My issue wasn't with robots.txt, but making sure that the jQuery $.post statement wouldn't be run. The solution I went with was using a $.post in jQuery to /visits/add and then robots.txt with User-agent: * Disallow: /visits/add

Answer (score 1):

If you're handling your count by a server side HTTP request, you could filter any user agents that contain the word 'Googlebot'. A quick Google search shows me a couple of Googlebot user agent examples:

```
Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

Comment: This list contains many of the user agents used by bots: http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/internet/google/googlebot-spoofer/

Comment: That's exactly the page I found :) It'll be worth maybe checking to see if the user agent matches any of the known bots and if so, don't increase the hit count.

Comment: Not a bad solution. Although it seems as if this means more work is handled on our servers than using a jQuery+robots to actually stop bots from running the function.

Comment: This is true. If you'd like to take some of the load off the server, you could get jQuery to check for the user agent using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/